# How can I pass object as a array to slice

Tags: javascript

I found a [link](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/#JavaScripts_Apply_and_Call_Methods) about javascript,Here I understand how `call` will work

In the link, those guys provide the following example.

```
var anArrayLikeObj = {0:"Martin", 1:78, 2:67, 3:["Letta", "Marieta", "Pauline"], length:4 }
Array.prototype.slice.call (anArrayLikeObj, 0)
```

got the output in the following way.

```
["Martin", 78, 67, Array[3]
```

what they provide, it's working fine.For my understanding purpose I modified object(anArrayLikeObj) in the following way.

```
var anArrayLikeObj = {0:"Martin", 1:78, 2:67, 3:["Letta", "Marieta", "Pauline"]}
Array.prototype.slice.call (anArrayLikeObj, 0)
```

getting output emptyArray([]).So I didn't understand both are objects,the only difference property `length`.Because of that it's not working my approach.

Is there any reason?

Comment: As you noticed the `length` property is needed for an object to be "array-like"

Comment: What @dystroy said, also - it's specified here http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.10 you might want to read it :)

Comment: Its also worth noting that length will be automatically updated if you use an Array and will not if you don't.

Answer (score 3):

The term array-like in JavaScript refers to objects that have both non-negative integer properties and a numeric `length` property. Therefore, your second object is not array-like.

Notice that `Array.prototype.slice` is using the value *you* provide in `length` to determine how many elements are in the object. Changing that value creates a different output, regardless of the object's *actual* size.

Comment: The term "array like" does not really refer to anything in JavaScript and it's not defined very well. In JavaScript typing is behavioral - "array like" simply means "behaves like an array would".

Comment: I agree that "array like" simply means "behaves like an array would" which means "has both non-negative integer properties and a numeric length property." So, cool. We agree.

Comment: @lwburk Thanks you man,It's very useful information.Where can I find these type information.

Comment: @Hanumath https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice